# How to query Excel like database in Javascript-NodeJs package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, exceljs, testautomationfx

I have requirement to access the excel file like a database in javascript to pump large size of test data. For the same requirement Fillo Excel API provided solution for JAVA solutions. Now I am looking for same type in Javascript.